# Should I add a unique constraint to a UUID column?

Tags: database

I'm adding a UUID column to one of my tables so I can easily provision API keys. Should I bother adding a unique constraint to the column? I don't want to have duplicate API keys but on the other hand, the odds of a collision on generating the UUID values is infinitesimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take into consideration if you are going to join tables based on this column or perform any operations like filter etc. If so, you will need to create a unique key on the UUID column as it will help retrieve data faster.

Comment: I'm planning on adding an index as I'll do look ups against this data. It does appear that a unique index would be faster than a regular one.

Comment: There should not be any difference between an unique index and an non-unique one in your scenario since it's a B-tree index. Unique index only tells the DB to disallow duplicates. Refer to this link for more clarification: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_index_unique_vs_non_unique.htm

Comment: @BlackSwan could you provide your reasoning or some documentation to support your statement in your answer?

Comment: @AdrianB. this is of course language and implementation dependent, but in some languages the `UNIQUE` constraint is enforced by a unique index, so add a unique constraint if it is desirable to have an index over the column.